# MongoDB installation Ubuntu 12.04 LTS errors

Tags: mongodb, installation, ubuntu

I need some help with my MongoDB installation on a clean, fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with no nonsense installed. I thought it would be a piece of cake, but I got some errors and the Ubuntu-forums didn't had the answer I was looking for.

Before I started with the actual installation of MongoDB, I wanted the server to be up-to-date, so I typed:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I went to to website from MongoDB (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and followed their tutorial, so I typed:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

At this point I have MongoDB installed. Like we all know, in order to use MongoDB you need to start it using a terminal and after that you'll be able to connect with a seperated terminal/connection.

So, I typed:

```
ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> ^C

ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongod
2015-03-27T12:38:54.773+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2015-03-27T12:38:54.774+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Ofcourse, I don't want to use stackoverflow right away, before doing my own investigation first. I went online to look for answers and I noticed that lots of people using "export LC_ALL=C" to fix the variable problem. I also tried using dpkg.

```
ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ export LC_ALL=C

ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
root@ubuntu-vm:~# dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = "c",
    LC_PAPER = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_AU.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_BW.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_CA.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_GB.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_HK.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_IN.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_NG.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_NZ.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_PH.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_SG.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_ZM.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
  en_ZW.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)
up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Apparently, that didn't work properly, so I needed to continue my search. I came up with another solution: edit the **/etc/default/grub file** with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="transparent_hugepage=never"** and then I got this:

```
ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongo
Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set.
Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.

ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongod
2015-03-27T12:56:19.085+0100 F CONTROL  Failed global initialization:
BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_*
environment variables are set correctly.
```

So, practically I have no idea what went wrong. I looked all over the internet and couldn't find the exact answer I am looking for. I did a clean install just like the website said. A few months ago I did the same tutorial and everything was working perfectly, with version 2.6.x, this is 3.0.1.

Could you guys help me out? Any comments/tips/tricks will be sincerely appreciated :)

Comment: I know that I got the hugepages error when installing the Tokudb plugin for MariaDB. I just edited the file (sudo) and the problem went away. Did nothing with GRUB. Apparently Oracle's Linux (so-called "unbreakable" - giggle) doesn't like it much either - I looked for setting to never problems or similar - apparently, it's not that big a deal. I was using a Fedora distro - yum install, not apt-get. HTH

Answer (score 2):

There is actually nothing really wrong here, at least not based on what you have included in the question.  Go back to this point:

```
ubuntu-user@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongo

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-03-27T12:37:30.430+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> ^C
```

At this point you have a running `mongod` (the procedure you followed installs it as a service), and you have successfully connected to it using the `mongo` shell, it just has a hugepages warning - that is something you should fix long-term but it does not prevent MongoDB from running.

You then exited the shell and attemped to start another `mongod` for some reason (you do not need to, the service is still running).  If you run `mongod` without a config file or any options, it will attempt to start with its defaults (port 27017, data directory = `/data/db`).  In this case `/data/db` does not exist and so you get the error and it terminates.

To fix the error in terms of the hugepages you can alter `grub.conf` file, as outlined in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99172) but you may have made a mistake or omitted something when you made your changes.  It's also possible that you will lose those changes if/when you upgrade your kernel.  Hence I would recommend undoing your grub changes and trying the second option listed in the answer above, that is, add the command to your /etc/rc.local file.

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

As an added bonus, you can run this from the command line (as root), then restart the `mongod` service to confirm the changes have been picked up successfully.